# Could someone please help me with this matrix question

Tags: matrices

If $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices of same order then which of the following is 
true ?

A. $A+B$ is symmetric.

B. $A-B$ is symmetric.

C. Both $A$ and $B$.

D. None of these.

Comment: Least thing you could have done is take two matrices and see if their sum/difference/product is symmetric..

Comment: I did that, and it comes out that it is not symmetric in either case. But according to the question, the correct answer is C, both.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ themselves symmetric?

Comment: are you saying all matrices are symmetric??? I suppose the question is incomplete otherwise.. Are you sure you have written full question?

Comment: Yes. It is the complete question.
It says, A and B are any two square matrices of same order.
So whether or not A+B is symmetric?
and is A-B Symmetric ?

Comment: Then the question is wrong, as you have found a counterexample yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only true if $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and have the same size.

Note that $$(A + B)^t = A^t + B^t = A + B.$$

The last equality follows from the fact that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric. The case for the difference is left to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, it is true when A and B are symmetric but it is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: But the counterexamples you have found not enough to convince you that the question is incorrect?

Comment: Yes I was convinced but since it was from a good publication (Pearson) so I thought I might be missing something

Comment: You did not miss anything, only they missed the typo. Question your sources.

Comment: You are right. Anyway, thanks for your response and clearing my doubt.